# Mysql master/slave replication .[Bug?] Internal MySQLConnection object always connects to the same host?

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc, database-replication, mysql-connector

We use MySQL master-slave setup to store data used in our REST APIs.

We are planing to direct to master db-host or to slave db-host depend the a REST request parameter.

To achieve this , we use MySQL ReplicationDriver. We use MyBatis as a layer between DB and our API.Spring is being used as the IOC framework.

We have defined two methods as follows , which the same logic to retrieve data from the DB.
Only difference between these two methods is, one method has "readOnly=true" in @Transactional annotation, which will direct to "slave", and the other has "readOnly=false" which will direct to "master".

```
@Override
 @Transactional(value = "itemTrxManager", readOnly = true, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
  public Item getShopItemFromSlave(ItemGetKey itemKey, Options... opts) throws ItemException {
  ..
  }

 @Override
 @Transactional(value = "itemTrxManager", readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
  public Item getShopItemFromMaster(ItemGetKey itemKey, Options... opts) throws ItemException {
  ..
  }
```

But we noticed that internally ReplicationDriver (MySQLConnection object) always direct to the first host it connects to , and doesn't change after the change of "readOnly" flag.

ie : after starting our API , if we send request to use "slave" , ReplicationDriver will use "slave host" and even when we change to use "master", it still direct to "slave host".
Otherway around is the same : after starting our API , if we send request to use "master" , ReplicationDriver will use "master host" and then if change to use "slave", it still direct to "master host".

Notice that all the Logs (Apache DBCP,Spring DAO , MyBatis logs) shows it connects to the correct host , but after debugging we figured out the issues is in MySQL driver classes (MySQLConnection objects shows incorrect host names).ie Connection object retreived from Apache DBCP DataSource and the internal MySQLConnection object shows different host info.

for example ,following shows a snippet from our logs .Eventhough it says it connects to "slave" , when debugging the MySQL Driver internal class ReplicationDriver has information about "master".

> DEBUG [http-8080-2] [AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:365] -
>   Creating new transaction with name
>   [com.foo.bar.item.core.businesslogic.impl.MerchantCategoryBusinessLogicImpl.listMerchantCategory]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; 'itemTrxManager' DEBUG
>   [http-8080-2] [DataSourceTransactionManager.java:204] - Acquired
>   Connection [jdbc:mysql://master-host:3301/,
>   UserName=item_user@10.9.203.50, MySQL Connector Java] for JDBC
>   transaction DEBUG [http-8080-2] [DataSourceUtils.java:153] - Setting
>   JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://master-host:3301/,
>   UserName=item_user@10.9.203.50, MySQL Connector Java] read-only
>
> DEBUG [http-8080-2] [Slf4jImpl.java:47] - Creating a new SqlSession
>   DEBUG [http-8080-2] [Slf4jImpl.java:47] - Registering transaction
>   synchronization for SqlSession
>   [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@329203a8] DEBUG
>   [http-8080-2] [Slf4jImpl.java:47] - JDBC Connection
>   [jdbc:mysql://slave-host:3306/, UserName=item_user@10.9.203.50, MySQL
>   Connector Java] will be managed by Spring DEBUG [http-8080-2]
>   [Slf4jImpl.java:47] - ooo Using Connection
>   [jdbc:mysql://slave-host:3306/, UserName=item_user@10.9.203.50, MySQL
>   Connector Java] DEBUG [http-8080-2] [Slf4jImpl.java:47] - ==> 
>   Preparing: select merchant_category_id, custom_category_id,
>   merchant_id, parent_id, sibling_position, image_url, create_time,
>   update_time from glb_merchant_cat_tbl where merchant_id=?
>
> . . .
>
> DEBUG [http-8080-2] [Slf4jImpl.java:47] - Transaction synchronization
>   committing SqlSession
>   [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@329203a8] DEBUG
>   [http-8080-2] [Slf4jImpl.java:47] - Transaction synchronization
>   closing SqlSession
>   [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@329203a8] DEBUG
>   [http-8080-2] [DataSourceUtils.java:222] - Resetting read-only flag of
>   JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://slave-host:3306/,
>   UserName=item_user@10.9.203.50, MySQL Connector Java] DEBUG
>   [http-8080-2] [DataSourceTransactionManager.java:322] - Releasing JDBC
>   Connection [jdbc:mysql://master-host:3301/,
>   UserName=item_user@10.9.203.50, MySQL Connector Java] after
>   transaction DEBUG [http-8080-2] [DataSourceUtils.java:332] - Returning
>   JDBC Connection to DataSource

How so solve this issue ? This might be a bug in ReplicationDriver ?

**Update :**

This is our spring context :

```
<!-- this is needed for the annotated transactions to work -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="trx-manager-item" proxy-target-class="true" />

    <bean id="trx-manager-item" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="itemDataSource" />
        <qualifier value="itemTrxManager" />
    </bean>
```

Connection url:

> jdbc:mysql:replication://master-host:3301,master-slave:3301/item2_1?allowMasterDownConnections=true&roundRobinLoadBalance=true&autoReconnectForPools=true

Context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context>



<Resource name="jdbc/item"

auth="Container"

type="javax.sql.DataSource"

factory="com.foo.bar.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"

driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

defaultAutoCommit="false"

defaultTransactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED"

removeAbandonedTimeout="600"

timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"

minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"

logAbandoned="true"

poolPreparedStatements="true"

removeAbandoned="true"

testOnBorrow="false" 

testOnReturn="false"

validationQuery="select null"

testWhileIdle="true"

/>
```

Connection URL is set inside the com.foo.bar.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory class.

Comment: please provide your Spring data source configuration. how are you verifying which host transactions are routed to?

Comment: i posted the data-source configuration . We debugged into MySQL Driver level and noticed that objects of "MySQLConnection" class has incorrect routing host names.(even though Connection object from DBCP , MySQL Session ..etc contains correct host names)

Comment: once we change the "poolPreparedStatements" to "false" it worked fine.